# unintentionally early meetings

Tags: translation, expressions

I heard there is an expression in Japanese for when two people agree to meet at a certain time, but both arrive at the meeting point much earlier.

In that situation, when the two people see each other, the meeting gets effectively moved up with respect to the appointed time.

How would you describe such situation and is there indeed a set phrase? I couldn’t find one in the dictionaries.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I couldn't find one in my memory...

Comment: If there existed a set phrase what would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [繰り上げる](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B)?

An example in the link 会議の日取りを繰り上げた describe the situation where a meeting is rescheduled e.g. from 15 August to 10 August.

Note that there are other uses of 繰り上げる. E.g.

- 繰り上げ当選 is a situation where there is an election for 10 members but one of the top 10 votes resigns for some reason, and the 11th most voted person got elected - then this person's win is called 繰り上げ当選.

Comment: What about 前倒【まえだお】し（する）?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Good point. Actually 繰り上げる is used in [a definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%89%8D%E5%80%92%E3%81%97/#jn-207104). For that meaning, I think the two are interchangeable. As verb, both 前倒し(に)する and 前倒す are possible.